# Users answering their own questions and accepting those answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134847/install-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-same-usb#140734) link the user has answered his own question and accepted his own answer.

This is like cheating the system to gain reputation.

10 points for the accepted answer and 2 for accepting it.

What to do of such cases?

Comment: Hmm.  I usually vote those answers up.  (See jrg's answer.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16947/should-i-accept-my-own-answer-even-if-its-inspired-by-another-much-detailed-ans?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Nothing.

Since Stack Overflow began, it has been strongly encouraged for a user [to answer their own question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

In fact, [it's codified in the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions):

> It’s also OK to ask [and answer your own question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

The Official Stack Overflow blog says this:

> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.**

So in short, there is nothing wrong with that.

> Bottom line — **never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site.** Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.

There's even an option now for [users to answer their own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/):

[image]

Comment: Well thats not good i think but....its a backdoor to better reputation...

Comment: @Nirmik no it isn't. you don't get more reputation for accepting your own answer or anything like that.

Comment: Well m not saying more....but the standard 2 for accepting and the standard 10 for your answer being accpted....whereas it should just be 2 for accepting right??

Comment: @Nirmik no, you don't get either.

Comment: @Nirmik You cannot up vote your own answer and accepting own answers does not give you +15 rep. Also don't forget that he can only accept an answer himself has made 1 day after making it. Its ok to accept your own answers, nothing wrong with that, if there are any signs of trying to take advantage of that I am sure that the down votes that will come from accepting a bad answer are not worth the trouble. The system is perfect, don't sweat about it ;)

Comment: @Nirmik: To be perfectly clear: you do not get any rep from answering and accepting your own answer. You only get rep from upvotes to the question or answer from others.

Comment: okay...thanx a lot everyone..:) now the idea is clear.. :)